# addConnectionForRelationship without CoreData

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

There is an object called Sale that I get from server:

```
{
  "description": "New Sale",
  "new_price": 10,
  "prev_price": 15,
  "product:: "45F83"
}
```

And there is an object, Product, regarding which the sale exists:

```
{
  "id": "45F83",
  "name": "Blue Shirt Plus",
  "description": "Bigger Shirt"
}
```

I do not use CoreData and, therefore, I use RKObjectMapping, which doesn’t have the addConnectionForRelationship method.

Is there a way to make connection from Sale to Product using only a product id as property of Sale to build a relationships without RKEntityMapping?

Comment: No, there isn't. You will need to do it manually. Why don't you use core data?

Comment: The data changes every 5 minutes and it pointless to store it somewhere. I am not sure that using core data only for building relationships by ID is worth it. I was not :)

Comment: It doesn't matter how often it changes, it's about how much there is / how much you have in memory at any one time / automatic updates to the UI following changes...

Comment: The problem is that I need to load the whole bunch of Products to be able to connect it to 10 Sales I am going to display on the screen.

Comment: In what scenario? RestKit can do the linking for you if you use core data and you don't need to worry about loading anything. And you can use an FRC to trigger your UI updates and paginate the data into memory.

Comment: If I want only 20 sales (not all the sales, but only 20) and then I want all the products linked by the sales. Using Core Data, I need to download all the Products that exist on the server to make RestKit able to connect sales to products. Am I wrong? If not - that is not an option, because we have around million products on the server, and any sale can have any of them.

Comment: Core data has no bearing on that. So long as you download the linked products you have the details. Indeed you don't need to download any products directly as you can create stub objects from the product ids in the sales response...

Comment: @Wain, solving Slabko's problem should not necessitate using Core Data. There are many, many reasons NOT to use Core Data

Comment: I really wonder why this shouldn't be possible with RestKit. Seems like missing feature.

Comment: @IliasKarim, there really aren't that many reasons not to use Core Data, and it isn't a necessity to use Core Data to make the relationships as you could augment RestKit to create your own mapping data source which offers to find the existing object in your alternate data source and returns it for connection. The point is that Core Data is the standard data store which contains formalised relationships in iOS / Cocoa and therefore it is the chosen implementation.

Comment: @Wain I know of at least one very good reason for not introducing Core Data into your project: reducing complexity. But I guess if reducing complexity were a project goal one shouldn't use RestKit either XD

Comment: @Wain, I got the answer actually, you idea to use CoreData suggested me that it is not possible without it. But I agree with IliasKarim, first of all, CoreData is another level of complexity. There is whole bunch of apps that do not use CoreData and they live perfectly. In most cases those apps doesn’t require any storage, that is why they use RestKit - it is good for network communication.

Comment: Here is another story: the API that I use stores 1000K (a lot!) items of books. But app doesn’t sell all the books, it only shows special offers, which is about 10 active, each of which related to a book. The way you propose is download all the books (1000K) to CoreData only to be able to get 10 books for 10 special offers. No - really :). What I want, is to ask the network framework - download those 10 offers, and then restore the graph by downloading books for them. That it - CoreData is completely different story for that case. Aren’t you agree?

Comment: I most certainly would not suggest downloading 1M records when you only need ten! But that is completely unrelated to Core Data usage. If you have an object graph with relationships and more objects available than you can display on screen at one time then Core Data can be of benefit to you.